# How to draw a "not" colored text?

Tags: delphi, xor-drawing

I'm looking for a way to draw text with inverted colors.
For shapes, we have `TPenMode` that can be set to `pmNot`, but we can't do this for text. How can I do this instead?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Are you sure it will work with anti-aliased text?

Comment: @Andreas: Well, this part of the project doesn't need anti-aliased text; so it doesn't matter whether or not it will work.

Comment: I think you need GDI+ to control the outline of text.

Comment: Are you asking how to draw inverted text, or are you asking how to draw text with a custom pen? The title asks the former, but the body asks the latter, and they're two different questions. Please edit to make them match.

Comment: If you are asking this because you want inverted text to make get more contrast on your background, note that when the text color is grey, the inversion won't work.

Comment: RE: "NOT" colored text -- do you mean XOR? -- Like where each color is XOR'd with the background? -- (i.e. so you can write the same text twice to erase it, for example?)

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 A bit late to the party, right? Your example is correct. To be more precise, this question is about inverting the colors behind the text. 
Damn this question is so old! I don't do Delphi anymore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This does it:

```
procedure DrawTextNOT(const hDC: HDC; const Font: TFont; const Text: string; const X, Y: integer);
begin
  with TBitmap.Create do
    try
      Canvas.Font.Assign(Font);
      with Canvas.TextExtent(Text) do
        SetSize(cx, cy);
      Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
      Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, Width, Height));
      Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
      Canvas.TextOut(0, 0, Text);
      BitBlt(hDC, X, Y, Width, Height, Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCINVERT);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

Example:

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
  DrawTextNOT(Canvas.Handle, Canvas.Font, 'This is a test.', 20, 100);
//  DrawTextNOT(Canvas.Handle, Canvas.Font, 'This is a test.', 20, 100);
end;
```

You probably also want to disable ClearType. To do that, I refer you to [a previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716304/is-there-a-way-to-disable-font-anti-aliasing-when-using-textrect-aka-exttextout).

Comment: I just edited the answer so you do not need to provide the rectangle, and so the function respects the current font of the canvas.

Comment: you're always the best! it works well! ;) I'll take care about the rest of things so don't worry :x

Comment: Great answer as always!

Answer (score 2):

GDI text isn't drawn with a pen. Have you considered drawing the text to a temporary bitmap, and copying with `BitBlt`? There's probably a combination of the `dwRop` raster operations that can get the effect you're looking for.