# Delphi TextRect in Windows GDI

Tags: delphi, text, gdi, rect, drawtext

Is there an analogue of `Delphi TextRect` in GDI? I looked at `DrawText, DrawTextEx`, but I didn't find what I needed. I need to draw a percent text of a progress bar that is divided in two color parts, e.g. the left part of the text is black, the right one is white. So as usually in all progress bars.

[image]

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: In GDI, you can use `TextOut` and `DrawText` (`DrawTextEx`). These contain *more* features than the Delphi functions. What feature are you looking for exactly? How does your `TCanvas` code look like? Why do you feel you need to abandon the `TCanvas`?

Comment: but I need a main idea of TextRect (where I can cut a part of a text and not to draw it). I don't see it in DrawText/Ex. Please see a posted picture, I need to draw a text like in TGauge (or other progress bars).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for the [`ExtTextOut`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-exttextouta) function.

Sample:

```
procedure TForm4.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
const
  S = 'This is a sample text';
begin
  ExtTextOut(Canvas.Handle, 10, 10, ETO_CLIPPED,
    Rect(40, 10, 100, 100), PChar(S), length(S), nil)    
end;
```

But I think that what you really want to do, is to draw ['NOT-coloured text'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053282/how-to-draw-a-not-colored-text):

```
procedure DrawTextNOT(const hDC: HDC; const Font: TFont; const Text: string; const X, Y: integer);
begin
  with TBitmap.Create do
    try
      Canvas.Font.Assign(Font);
      with Canvas.TextExtent(Text) do
        SetSize(cx, cy);
      Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
      Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, Width, Height));
      Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
      Canvas.TextOut(0, 0, Text);
      BitBlt(hDC, X, Y, Width, Height, Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCINVERT);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm4.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
const
  S = 'This is a sample text';
var
  ext: TSize;
begin
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
  Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, Width div 2, Height));
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  Canvas.FillRect(Rect(Width div 2, 0, Width, Height));
  ext := Canvas.TextExtent(S);

  DrawTextNOT(Canvas.Handle, Canvas.Font, S, (Width - ext.cx) div 2,
    (Height - ext.cy) div 2);
end;
```

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [rejbrand.se](http://privat.rejbrand.se/nottext.png))</sub>

Comment: @maxfax: OK, *now* (better late than never -- I'm a bit 'slow' sometimes...) I see what you are missing from `TextRect`. The WinAPI function you are looking for is `ExtTextOut`. Still, I wonder if it isn't simpler just to draw a single NOT-coloured text anyway...